# Debian unbootable after second install

Tags: debian, boot, grub, uefi, bios

I have debian on `/dev/sda`, I added a new drive `/dev/sdc` and installed a separate debian on it, now when it boots the new grub loads and it doesn't have my old debian in it.

When I go into the bios and manually select my old installation I get:

> Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key

Since both drives should have grub, how can I tell my bios to load it from my first drive, or effectively how can I get both instances of debian bootable?

EDIT:

Running `os-prober` does not detect my old installation, which has me a little worried, but I don't understand what's happening since its partitions shouldn't have been touched by the new installation? If I mount its `/boot/efi` partition I see that there are files there.

Comment: please share result of  fdisk -l commad .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by inserting my Debian bootable USB and going into rescue mode. From there I chose the repair grub option, and rebooted.

At this point my main instance was bootable but all the other options in its grub were broken, so after logging in I did `update-grub` and then it was all good.

I'm curious why that happened tho.